# Does $(\langle w, x \rangle + b) = ||x - x'||$ hold?

Tags: support-vector-machine, linear-algebra

Currently, I am trying to understand the mathematics of SVM's using the textbook 'Mathematics for Machine Learning' by Deisenrot et. al.

On page 375, they define the distance between a point $x$ and the separating hyperplane as the length of the distance vector $||x - x'||$, where $x'$ corresponds to the orthogonal projection of x onto the hyperplane.

Subsequently, they formulate the following condition to express that any point's distance from the hyperplane should be greater than or equal to some constant r:

$$y(\langle w, x \rangle + b) \geq r$$

- $y ∈ {0, 1}$ representing the class of $x$
- $w$ normal vector and $b$ the bias.

So my question is: Does $(\langle w, x \rangle + b) = ||x - x'||$ hold?

If that's the case, I would be thankful for some hints on how both sides of the equation are related.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your missing the fact that ***$r$*** is not a random constant, but precisely the minimum distance we want to ensure between each point and the separation hyperplane (called margin). And indeed in the book they use *$r$* to define the distance from a generic vector $a$ to the hyperplane as well:

$a = a' + r\frac{w}{||w||}$

Since $\frac{w}{||w||}$ is a normalized vector, we can consider $a'$ as the  x coordinate of $a$ in the coordinates system defined by $w$, vector orthogonal to the hyperplane and the hyperplane itself, whereas $r$ represent the y coordinate (see drawing below, apologies for the awful quality). To be able to separate 2 points $x_1$ and $x_2$ into 2 different classes, we want them to fall into different sides of the hyperplane. By imposing

$y(\langle w, a \rangle + b) \geq r$

we're also saying that we don't want the points to just fall into different sides of the hyperplane, but they're y coordinate should also be bigger or equal to r (in absolute value).

So, to answer your question, $(\langle a x \rangle + b) = ||x - x'||$ is not really a correct statement but for a bunch of points instead will hold  $y(\langle w, a \rangle + b) = x - x'$ (i.e. the y coordinate of the point we want to classify express in the coordinates system of the hyperplane is equal to r, which means the point lies in the margin of the hyperplane).

[image]